# How to access serial port from two different application in c#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am using three WCF services, one to monitor the swipe card reader using serial port which receives data when user swipes the card. Data is then sent to another service which validates data and calls other service to open the gate for the user which associate to that swipe port.

Since serial port is already opened and monitored by first WCF service, another service can't access the port to send command to open the door. When I try to fix this by creating a Singleton class around swipe port object, I can able to get the same object but state is not maintained insense the port says it's not opened but actually it is opened through first service.

I just placed my port class. Any idea or suggestion please.

```
public class Port : SerialPort
{     
    public Port(string port) : base(port)
    {
    }

    public static Port Instance
    {
        get { return Nested.myPort; }
    }

    class Nested
    {
        static Nested() { }

        internal static Port swipePort;

        public static Port myPort
        {
            get
            {
                if (swipePort == null)
                    swipePort = new Port("COM4");

                if (!swipePort.IsOpen)
                    swipePort.Open();
                return swipePort;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by WCF services; are they hosted within IIS, within a custom host application, or are they Windows services? And is there a particular reason for keeping those services apart?

Comment: WCF service 1,3 which reads port data and writes data are hosted in windows service, these services are apart because 2nd wcf service(IIS hosted) which validates user entry act as pub/sub to silverlight client, once user is not allowed due to invalid entry access this can be override by user using silverlight application which inturn calls the third wcf service to open the gate.

Comment: A singleton object will not help much, since you will still have a single instance per service. Make a separate service which accepts and queues commands for sending, and raises an event whenever data is received. This will also help you abstract the actual port implementation.

Answer (score 5):

The same port cannot be opened twice. I would suggest that one WCF service is responsible for communicating over the serial port and the others talk to that service. Use client certificates or another authentication scheme so that calls to the service cannot result in unauthorised "Open Door" requests, for example.

Your example above creates a static instance of the port but static instances are only "static" in the context of the same AppDomain. Depending on your hosting model, the two WCF services could be in different AppDomains. Also, reads and writes to serial ports are not thread-safe so you will encounter problems using a SerialPort in this manner.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, so i cant handle this with this fashion? Is some other way to communicate to serial port which is already open?

Comment: @paras: not in a safe manner. If you think about how serial port class works, you will see that there is a point where the input buffer needs to be cleared (after you call the `Read` method or handle the event). If multiple processes are reading the same data, it is difficult to define the right moment when to clear the buffer. If multiple apps were to write/read to the same port, you would end up with overlapping transmitted data, and missing bytes in the received data.

Comment: @paras: as Phill suggested, a better way is not only to create a dedicated service for handling communication, but also to abstract the port at the binary level, and only expose higher level commands and parsed responses to other services.

Comment: No, the only way is to create a gateway to the port through one point. Doing this will help you maintain state through multiple service reads and writes. As a commenter mentioned above this also allows you to abstract the port implementation which is good application design.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, i will implement the same way as yopu guys suggested.